# Set the value to JtextField in Jtable : JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield

I try to set default path and set this value to JtextField. When I add new row and select the path it works. But when the script is first start, I try to give default path to first row but it doesn't take the correct string.

This is the screenshot : I give the path -> //bie-pvcs-01/logs_122 but it takes role_script.MainGuiComp@127077b

[image]

Here is my code :

```
public class MainGui extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField userNametextField;
private JLabel searchLabel,lblNewLabel_2;
private JTable CompTable = null;
private CompTableModel CompModel = null;
private JButton addButton = null;
private String folder = File.separator+File.separator+"bie-pvcs-01"+File.separator+"logs_122"+File.separator;
private JComboBox<String> comboBox;
private JLabel pathWarningLabel;
private ArrayList<String> plist = new ArrayList<>();
File lastDirectory = new File(File.separator+File.separator+"bie-pvcs-01"+File.separator+"logs_122"+File.separator);
private JTextField textField;
private JTable table;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
    }
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainGui frame = new MainGui();
                Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
                int w = frame.getSize().width;
                int h = frame.getSize().height;
                int x = (dim.width-w)/4;
                int y = (dim.height-h)/2;
                frame.setLocation(x, y);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public MainGui() {
    getContentPane().setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaptionText);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 650, 650);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    setTitle("Role Finding Script");


    CompTable = CreateCompTable();
    JScrollPane CompTableScrollpane = new JScrollPane(CompTable, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    CompTableScrollpane.setBounds(10, 325, 599, 108);
    CompTableScrollpane.getViewport().setBackground(Color.white);
    getContentPane().add(CompTableScrollpane);

    JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("   Username  :");
    lblUsername.setFont(new Font("LucidaSans", Font.BOLD, 13));
    lblUsername.setBounds(10, 111, 172, 30);
    Border border = BorderFactory.createRaisedSoftBevelBorder();
    border = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder();
    lblUsername.setBorder(border);
    getContentPane().add(lblUsername);


    userNametextField = new JTextField();
    userNametextField.setBounds(216, 111, 393, 30);
    userNametextField.setFont(new Font("LucidaSans", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    getContentPane().add(userNametextField);
    userNametextField.setColumns(20);


    JLabel lblRole = new JLabel("    Roles        :");
    lblRole.setFont(new Font("LucidaSans", Font.BOLD, 13));
    lblRole.setBounds(10, 174, 172, 30);
    border = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder();
    lblRole.setBorder(border);
    getContentPane().add(lblRole);

    comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
    comboBox.setBounds(216, 175, 393, 30);
     //     comboBox.addItem("CHANGE-MANAGER");
     //     comboBox.addItem("PCMS-PART-MANAGER");
     //     comboBox.addItem("PMCS-ROLE-MANAGER");
    comboBox.addItem("VR_ANALYST");

    getContentPane().add(comboBox);


    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    textField.setColumns(20);
    textField.setBounds(216, 239, 393, 30);
    getContentPane().add(textField);

    searchLabel = new JLabel("Searching.. Please wait..");
    searchLabel.setFont(new Font("LucidaSans", Font.BOLD, 13));
    searchLabel.setBounds(216, 564, 195, 30);
    searchLabel.setVisible(false);
    getContentPane().add(searchLabel);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Execute !");
    btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("LucidaSans", Font.BOLD, 13));
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            //check the username
            System.out.println(CompTable.getRowCount());
            if(userNametextField.getText() == null || userNametextField.getText().equals("")){
                lblNewLabel_2.setText("Please filled in the username part !");               
            }else if(CompTable.getRowCount() == 0){
                pathWarningLabel.setText("Please add at least one path..");
                pathWarningLabel.setVisible(true);
            }else{
                for(int i=0; i<CompTable.getRowCount(); i++){
                    if(CompTable.getValueAt(i, 0).toString() != null && !CompTable.getValueAt(i, 0).toString().equals("")){
                        plist.add(CompTable.getValueAt(i,0).toString());
                    }
                }
                for(String a : plist){
                    System.out.println("1" + a);
                }
                if(plist.size() != 0){
                    searchLabel.setVisible(true);
                    SearchingClass task = new SearchingClass(searchLabel,userNametextField.getText(),comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString(),plist,textField.getText());
                    //run the script
                    task.execute();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(227, 523, 126, 30);
    getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("+");
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            CompModel.addRow("");
        }
    });
    btnNewButton_1.setBounds(566, 481, 43, 23);
    getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);

    JLabel lblPleaseSelectThe = new JLabel("Please select the log files directories");
    lblPleaseSelectThe.setForeground(Color.RED);
    lblPleaseSelectThe.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblPleaseSelectThe.setBounds(180, 300, 297, 14);
    getContentPane().add(lblPleaseSelectThe);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Add New Path");
    lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.ITALIC, 11));
    lblNewLabel_1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(444, 481, 126, 23);
    getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);

    Color my_color1 = new Color(204,74,20);
    JLabel lblRoleFindingScript = new JLabel("Role Finding Script ");
    lblRoleFindingScript.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
    lblRoleFindingScript.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblRoleFindingScript.setForeground(my_color1);
    lblRoleFindingScript.setBounds(197, 43, 297, 30);
    getContentPane().add(lblRoleFindingScript);

    lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("");
    lblNewLabel_2.setForeground(Color.RED);
    lblNewLabel_2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.ITALIC, 10));
    lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(226, 150, 282, 14);
    getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_2);

    pathWarningLabel = new JLabel();
    pathWarningLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.ITALIC, 11));
    pathWarningLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    pathWarningLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
    pathWarningLabel.setBounds(140, 444, 384, 14);
    pathWarningLabel.setVisible(false);
    getContentPane().add(pathWarningLabel);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
    lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("valeo2.png"));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 11, 172, 89);
    getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

    JLabel lblRegex = new JLabel("   Regex        :");
    lblRegex.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 13));
    lblRegex.setBounds(10, 239, 172, 30);
    border = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder();
    lblRegex.setBorder(border);
    getContentPane().add(lblRegex);

}

public JTable CreateCompTable() {
    CompModel = new CompTableModel();

    CompModel.addRow(folder);
//  CompModel.addRow("");

    table = new JTable(CompModel);
    table.setRowHeight(new CompCellPanel().getPreferredSize().height);
    table.setTableHeader(null);
    CompCellEditorRenderer compCellEditorRenderer = new CompCellEditorRenderer();
    table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, compCellEditorRenderer);
    table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, compCellEditorRenderer);
    return table;
}

class CompTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    public void addRow(String string) {
        super.addRow(new Object[]{new Comp(string)});

    }

}

class CompCellPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel labelWith = new JLabel("Path : ");
    private JTextField lowerField = new JTextField();
    private JButton browseButton = new JButton("browse");
    private JButton removeButton = new JButton("remove");

    CompCellPanel() {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        removeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //  JTable table = (JTable) SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JTable.class, (Component) e.getSource());
                int row = table.getEditingRow();
                table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
                ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRow(row);
            }
        });

        browseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //  JTable table = (JTable) SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JTable.class, (Component) e.getSource());
                int row = table.getEditingRow();
                Chooser frame = new Chooser();
                table.getModel().setValueAt(frame.fileName, row, 0);
                lowerField.setText(frame.fileName);
            }
        });

        lowerField.setEditable(false);

        add(labelWith);
        add(lowerField);
        add(browseButton);
        add(removeButton);

    }
    public void setComp(Comp Comp) {
        lowerField.setText(Comp.lower); 
    }

    public Comp getComp() {
        return new Comp(lowerField.getText());
    }
}

class CompCellEditorRenderer extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellRenderer, TableCellEditor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private CompCellPanel renderer = new CompCellPanel();
    private CompCellPanel editor = new CompCellPanel();

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        renderer.setComp((Comp) value);
        return renderer;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        editor.setComp((Comp) value);
        return editor;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return editor.getComp();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
        return false;
    }
}
class Comp {
    String lower;

    public Comp(String text) {
        this.lower = text;
    }
}

class Chooser extends JPanel {
    //File chooser class
    JFileChooser chooser;
    String fileName;

    public Chooser() {
        chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    //  chooser.setCurrentDirectory(lastDirectory);
        int r = chooser.showOpenDialog(new JPanel());
        if (r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
    //      lastDirectory = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        }
    }
}
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you store values in `JTabel` like your own objects(`Comp`). Try to replace in your `btnNewButton` `ActionListener` method next lines:

```
 for(int i=0; i<CompTable.getRowCount(); i++){
       if(CompTable.getValueAt(i, 0).toString() != null && !CompTable.getValueAt(i, 0).toString().equals("")){
             plist.add(CompTable.getValueAt(i,0).toString());
       }
 }
```

by that:

```
   for(int i=0; i<CompTable.getRowCount(); i++){
         String value = ((Comp)CompTable.getValueAt(i, 0)).lower;
         if(value!= null && !value.isEmpty()){
               plist.add(value);
         }
   }
```

it helps you. Because when you use `getValueAt()` method you get `Comp` instance, you can cast it and get value from that object.

Also read about [name convention](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm).